# AJAX request to an Express server doesn't send anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express, xmlhttprequest

So I created a `To-Do` app that when you input something in the field, it's supposed to make an `AJAX request` to the `Express` server with the input data and then `Express` server(`POST`) does push that data into an array(`Items`) and then finally `EJS` renders it(By using `ForEach` and getting the `item property` of each `object` inside)

Now the problem is that whenever I submit it, it seems like it doesn't send anything at all, `req.body` is empty and the events I attached to the `XHR request` don't show anything but 3 `events`:

**onprogress**

```
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 2, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost:3000/todo", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }
```

**onerror**

```
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost:3000/todo", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }
```

**onloadend**

```
XMLHttpRequest { onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, responseURL: "http://localhost:3000/todo", status: 0, statusText: "", responseType: "", response: "" }
```

As you see, the `readyState` is 4 but `statusText, status, responseType, response` don't show anything. Status is 0 and the others are empty. What's wrong? I tried by using `Fetch API` but it didn't work...either, I don't understand what's the problem although I'm sure the problem is in the `AJAX` request but I can't figure it out.

This is `HTML` file(By using `EJS` as a view engine):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>To-do Application</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../Public/Assets/Styles.css" />
  <script src="../Public/Scripts/Add.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="todo-table">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Write an item here" required>
      <button id="Add">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <% data.forEach(function(element){ %>
        <li> <%= element.item %> </li>
      <% }) %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the whole server set-up(`Express`):

```
let express = require("express");
let toDocontroller = require("./Controllers/toDoController");
let bodyparser = require("body-parser");
let urlencoded = bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

//set up express
let app = express();
// set up view engine
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
// use Public folder
app.use("/Public", express.static("Public"));
app.use(bodyparser.json());
// listen for a port
app.listen(3000);
// Running Controller
toDocontroller(app, urlencoded);
```

And this is server set up of POST/Delete/GET requests(The important ones):

```
let items = [];
module.exports = function(app, urlencoded) {
  app.get("/todo", function(req, res) {
    res.render("toDo", { data: items });
  });
  app.post("/todo", urlencoded, function(req, res) {
    items.push(req.body);
    console.log(req.body);
  });
  app.delete("/todo:item", function(req, res) {});
};
```

`Req.body` is `{}`
And finally this is the Javascript file that I use it to AJAX request to the server with the method of POST:

```
let form = document.querySelector("form");

let valueToAdd = document.querySelector("input").value;
let readyValue = { item: valueToAdd };
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/todo", true);
request.send(readyValue);
form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function() {
    request.onabort = function() {
      console.log("onabort ", request);
    };
    request.onerror = function() {
      console.log("onerror ", request);
    };
    request.onload = function() {
      console.log("onload ", request);
    };
    request.onloadend = function() {
      console.log("onloadend ", request);
    };
    request.onloadstart = function() {
      console.log("onloadstart ", request);
    };
    request.onprogress = function() {
      console.log("onprogress ", request);
    };
    request.ontimeout = function() {
      console.log("ontimeout ", request);
    };
  },
  true
);
```

If I wasn't clear enough, please tell me.

Comment: Try stringifying the readyValue with `JSON.stringify( readyValue )` so that you POST a JSON string instead of a javascript object.

Comment: @Shilly  Yeah I did that before. It doesn't work and shows the same results.

Comment: What function triggers this AJAX request? If you use a submit button inside a form, you might need to prevent the default behaviour so that the function will run before the page refreshes. So can you give more context how the AJAX call is triggered?

Comment: @Shilly It's not a submit button. It's a normal button so no need to prevent the default behaviour. Also there is no "Method: Post, Action" on the form so I don't think it refreshes(although the page spins in the browser) The AJAX call is triggered I guess is when it submits(the event listener)

Comment: Can you add the code of that event listener? I assume that the clientside JS code shown is inside a function, since your form.onsubmit does not contain the request.send() part. Or is this all the client code there is? In that case, you submit the form on load instead of by clicking on the button, which would explain why there's no value being send.

Comment: @Shilly Yeah, I put request.send outside the event listener because it didn't show that it didn't affect it at all. This is the code after putting it inside the event listener:  `form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function() {
    request.send(JSON.stringify(readyValue)); // the rest of the console.logs here}` it still doesn't work though(the same exact results)

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem. Look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfpmah2z/1/  After adding a valid URL and a button to submit the request, it works for me. If you open the network tab you can inspect that the fiddle is trying to POST to the url with the bdoy being whatever your typed into the input. So we can't really help more without being able to replicate the issue.

Comment: @Shilly  Wait how you're seeing that it works? For me, it doesn't send any POST request when I press Click or Send button, it also has almost the same error messages I get.

Comment: In the network tab of the dev tools? F12 in most browsers. Which debugger do you use? It shows me a POST request to `http://someurl.com`, which gets denied since it's a fake address without the correct credentials. But you can still inspect the request that the browser tried to send, and it shows me a payload of `{"item":"whatever we type in input"}`.

Comment: @Shilly Wait, I don't understand. That's not what shows to me at all. In Network dev tool(Firefox v61) it only shows me GET requests whenever I click send/add exactly like with my above problem, heck it even gives me the same error messages(Status...etc are all empty) I just don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: I don't have firefox, but both in IE11 and Chrome, I can see the post request and the body. https://imagebin.ca/v/4DrZl4trfPjo   Can you maybe post the entire script somewhere, since the code you have shown here works, assuming that it's bound to the click event of the button and that your URL is valid.

Comment: @Shilly the report of your script or my script(to-do)?

Comment: Mine, with the event listener for the click event and a valid url starting with `http://`. But the difference between our versions is minimal. I only added the click even tto the button, added JSON.stringify and changed the url. The rest is your code copy pasted.

Comment: @Shilly https://imgur.com/FF3SOB9  https://i.imgur.com/hhIu8O1.gif https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/24b620a9-fce4-42ba-828e-8b25c9cce774.png

Comment: Can you try in a different browser? I just downloaded firefox and I can't see the POST request either. I just get the error message as well that the request was blocked. But my thoughts then are, if the request did not get sent to begin with, why would it be blocked? So this is a firefox issue that you can't see the POST request there. Still does not explain why the server can't read the body either. But I'm kind of out of ideas here, don't think I can do much more. Good luck.

Comment: @Shilly Is there are nothing I can do ):?

Comment: Try creating a stack overflow snippet that actually demonstrates the problem. Or show the entire script where this is part of so that we see the actual click event handler. Your code does not show HOW the ajax event is triggered, so we''re assuming it  is tied to the click event of the Add button. Maybe there's an issue in your click event handler?

Comment: @Shilly Dude, I posted all the code above. It's like has everything(HTML, scripts, Express server...etc) basically everything plus the error messages fom console.

Comment: Isn't there a click event on the button? If not, and this is all the javascript code for the browser, your body is always empty because the request gets posted on page load instead of when you click the button. And when the page loads, the input is empty since you didn't provide a default value. Hence my Very First question was: `What function triggers this AJAX request?`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was in the strange behavior of the form. By using "`onsumbit = return false`" it disabled it and let the request work. It got solved.

Comment: Nice that you got it working! What you state is basically preventing the default behaviour of the form. Which I asked about and you said wasn't the issue, so I didnt look further that direction. No wonder we could not find the problem. :)

Comment: Yeah.Sorry for that. I thought that without action/method, the form won't have any default behaviours. Thank you for trying to help me earlier though.